# How can I convert all UTF8 Unicode characters in a string to their relevant Codepoints using bash/shell/zsh?

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, zsh

There seem to be loads of questions about converting 'Codepoints' to utf8, but I can't find an answer anywhere to do it the other way around.

I want to run a script which will convert a string such as `My` to `MyU+1F4D4`.

I have tried something like this: `DECODEDSTRING=$(echo "My" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT)` but I can't seem to figure out what is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: more zsh these days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `perl`, works in any shell as long as the arguments are encoded in UTF-8:

```sh
$ perl -CA -E 'for my $arg (@ARGV) { say map { my $cp = ord; $cp > 127 ? sprintf "U+%04X", $cp : $_ } split //, $arg }' "My"
MyU+1F4D4
```

Non-ASCII codepoints are printed as U+XXXX (0-padded, more hex digits if needed), ASCII ones as human-readable letters.

---

Or for maximum speed, a C program that does the same:

```c
// Compile with: gcc -o print_unicode -std=c11 -O -Wall -Wextra print_unicode.c                                                                                                                                                                                 
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <uchar.h>

#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 201112L
#error "Need C11 or newer"
#endif
#ifndef __STDC_UTF_32__
#error "Not using Unicode"
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // arguments should be encoded according to locale's character set
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""); 

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    char *s = argv[i];
    size_t len = strlen(argv[i]);
    mbstate_t state;
    memset(&state, 0, sizeof state);

    while (len > 0) {
      char32_t c;
      size_t rc = mbrtoc32(&c, s, len, &state);
      assert(rc != (size_t)-3);
      if (rc == (size_t)-1) {
        perror("mbrtoc32");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      } else if (rc == (size_t)-2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argument %d is incomplete!\n", i);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      } else if (rc > 0) {
        if (c > 127) {
          printf("U+%04" PRIXLEAST32, c);
        } else {
          putchar((char)c);
        }
        s += rc;
        len -= rc;
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```sh
$ ./print_unicode "My"
MyU+1F4D4
```

Comment: sweet, looks good!

Comment: In fact, the perl 1 liner works really really well, great stuff!