# Convert unicode array to string in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, unicode

I have an array of unicode points that i want to be able to convert back into characters and store it inside a variable as a string. In the example below it's just the "Hello World!" code point array but I could have any unicode number (up to 16 bits).

```bash
array=( 72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100 33 )
```

I checked:

- [How to convert \uXXXX unicode to UTF-8 using console tools in *nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795702/how-to-convert-uxxxx-unicode-to-utf-8-using-console-tools-in-nix)
- [How can I convert all UTF8 Unicode characters in a string to their relevant Codepoints using bash/shell/zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187233/how-can-i-convert-all-utf8-unicode-characters-in-a-string-to-their-relevant-code)

and other online resources but I still can't figure out how to do this. I tried things like:

```bash
temp=
for c in ${array[@]}; do
        temp+="\U$c"
done
printf %b "$temp"
```

I also saw bash has a new feature that allows you to do either `echo -e '\Uxxxxx'` or `$'\Uxxx'` but in my case it doesn't work since even if i iterate over the array and store each code point inside a variable `i`, the single quotes would prevent bash from expanding it in this case: `echo $'\U$i'`, i even tried `echo "$'\U$i'"`.

I'm utterly clueless on how to do this with pure bash in a simple way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that's messing you up is that your array is full of the *decimal* numbers of the codepoints, but the `\U` notation takes *hexidecimal* numbers. So for example, the first element in the array is "72" -- in decimal, that's the code for "H", but in hex it's equivalent to decimal 114, which is the code for "r".

So to use `\U` notation, you first need to convert the numbers to hex, which you can do with `printf %x`:

```
for c in "${array[@]}"; do
    temp+="\\U$(printf %x "$c")"    # Convert dec->hex, add \U
done
printf %b "$temp"    # Convert \U<codepoint> to actual characters
```

As dave_thompson_085 pointed out in a comment, you can simplify this even further by converting the entire array with a single `printf`:

```
printf %b "$(printf '\\U%x' "${array[@]}")"
```

Comment: And instead of looping you can give the first `printf` multiple arguments: `printf %b $( printf '\\U%x' "${array[@]}" )` _or_ `echo -e $( same )`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Nice! I'll add the concentric `printf` option, but I don't trust `echo -e` -- I had a bunch of scripts break once because an OS update included bash compiled with different options, and `echo`'s behavior with options changed.

Answer (score 1):

Shell scripts aren't do-it-all. For complex actions, they often rely on other utility programs that are common in linux installations. In this case, `iconv` can help.

```bash
array=( 72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100 33 )
temp=
for c in ${array[@]}; do temp+=$(printf '\\x%x' $c); done
temp=$(echo -ne $temp | iconv -f utf8)
printf %b "$temp"
```

Comment: This prints `爐ㄐ㠐㠑ㄲ蜑ㄑ㐐㠐〳`, it should print `Hello World!` even though i need it to support unicode, the unicode value of asci characters should be the same

Comment: I dont mind the use of any utility program though, as long as it comes built-in with most distros

Comment: @Lorenze Note that you'll likely need to test for code points with larger values (like chinese or such). My answer assumes the array is a list of integer bytes. Gordon Davisson's answer assumes the array is a list of integer code points.

Comment: My bad, i just got home let me test and i'll update the selected answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling the array `array` and then continue with `string` ??

```
tmp=""
arr=( 72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100 33 )
for c in "${arr[@]}"; do tmp+="\U$c"; done
printf %b "$tmp"
```

Comment: About the `array` and `string` names it's a mistake my bad, since i wanted to simplify the example, in my code it's stupidly called `string` even though it's actually an array. However this doesn't work, it prints `rāĈĈđ2đĔĈĀ3` instead of `Hello World!`